Show that a set $\mathcal B$ is an affine subspace iff $\forall P,Q \in \mathcal B$, the line $PQ$ is in $\mathcal B$
Like I stated in the title, I need to prove that:
Given a non-empty set $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathbb{A}^n$, $\mathcal{B}$ is an affine subspace of $\mathbb{A}^n$ if, and only if, for every $P$, $Q \in \mathcal{B}$, the line $PQ$ is contained in $\mathcal{B}$.

To prove the forward implication (if $\mathcal{B}$ is an affine subspace of $\mathbb{A}^n$, then for every $P$, $Q \in \mathcal{B}$ the line that touches $P$ and $Q$ is contained in $\mathcal{B}$) I came up with:
Let $V$ be the linear subspace associated with $\mathcal{B}$.
We know that, for every $P$ and $Q \in \mathcal{B}$, there exists $\vec{PQ} \in V$ such that $Q = P + \vec{PQ}$.
Since $V$ is a linear subspace, we know that $\lambda\vec{PQ} \in V \,, \forall\lambda$. Meaning that $<\vec{PQ}> \subseteq V$ and, so, $r = P + <\vec{PQ}>$, the line that touches $P$ and $Q$, is contained in $\mathcal{B}$.
The converse implication, however, I don't really see how to approach it. I thought about proving that $V$ is closed under scalar multiplication (since $r$ is in $\mathcal{B}$), but I don't know how to prove that it's closed under addition or that it contains the zero vector. Or even if this approach if correct.
Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you!

You want to prove that $\exists A\in \mathcal B$ and $V$ a subspace of direction of $A^n$, s.t. $\mathcal B=A+V$. $\mathcal B$ is non-empty. It seems reasonable to begin with : let $A\in \mathcal B$, isn't it ?

Then, you can work in pointed vector space $\mathcal B_A$. An affine space is a monster and we don't like monsters. So, we transform them in vector space as soon as we can :)

You want to prove that $\exists A\in \mathcal B$ and $V$ a subspace of the direction of $\mathbb A^n$, such that $\mathcal B=A+V$. $\mathcal B$ is non-empty. So,
Let $A\in \mathcal B$
We can work in pointed vector space $\mathbb A^n_A$.
Let $u\in \mathcal B$. Since the line that touches $A=0$ and $u$ is contained in $\mathcal B$, then $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb R, \lambda u\in \mathcal B$.
Let $u,v\in \mathcal B$. Then, by hypothesis, $u+\mathbb R(v-u)$ is contained in $\mathcal B$. Then, $u+\frac12(v-u)=\frac12(u+v)$, the midpoint of $uv$ is contained in $\mathcal B$. Then , as $A=0$ is also contained in $\mathcal B, \mathbb R (\frac12(u+v))$ too. In particular $2\times \frac12 (u+v)=u+v$ is contained in $\mathcal B$.
To conclude, $\mathcal B$ is a subspace of $\mathbb A^n_A$. In other words, $\mathcal B$ is an affine subspace of $\mathbb A^n.\square$


